# How is energy in terms of Intensity and Amplitude comparable to Energy in terms of Frequency?

Tags: atomic-physics, laser, frequency, gamma-rays, intensity

Let's take LASER light. It has a high energy ,in terms of *Amplitude*, let's take a *red  light*, of same frequency ,we are giving each of these to two atoms , now atom no $1$ is subjected to LASER light , an  electron in this  atom absorbs this and reemits as light of some frequency ,now atom no 2 is subjected to *red light*, an electron in this atom absorbs and re-emits a light of certain frequency ,now both the atom emit light of certain frequency ,are those frequency same?

(The LASER and Red light has the same frequency, incident frequency is same)

We know that :

$\mathrm{Intensity = \frac{Power \  (or) \ Energy} {Area}}$

$\implies$ $ \mathrm{Energy = Intensity × Area}$

This means that LASER light has more energy ,doesn't this mean that the frequency emitted by the atom absorbing  the LASER light is more ?

Another question related to this is why does sound of higher amplitude (or) Intensity tend to tear our ear and why doesn't sound of higher frequency tear our ear ?

How is "Energy in terms of Amplitude" comparable to "Energy in terms of frequency"?

Which has more energy $γ$ $rays$ (or) LASER ?

LASER can penetrate through Lead ,but I think $\gamma$ can be stopped with Lead.

Please forgive my stupidity .

Comment: Energy = Intensity x Area? It's average power, not energy.

Answer (score 0):

One of the results of quantum theory and the photoelectric effect, was that the intensity of a light (brightness) corresponds to the number of photons emitted.

In your first example, both the LASER light and the red light have the same frequency, (they are both red), and each is emitting photons of the same energy, from $E=hf$

However if the LASER has higher intensity, it's emitting more photons and would excite more atoms of the material that it's shone on, compared to the other red light.

The higher net energy is re-emitted because more atoms re-emit photons, but the energy of the photons that they re-emit would be the same.

Assuming that the LASER can penetrate lead, that's probably to do with the LASER being focused onto a tiny area, rather than about the energy of the photons.